# SharePoint Farm Configuration Error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, configuration-wizard

I'm trying to install SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise Edition SP 1. When I run the Configuration Wizard, select "Create a new server farm", and then enter the details for my Database server, it throws the following error:

`The username is invalid. The account must be a valid domain account.`

I've also tried running `New-SPConfigurationDatabase` command from SharePoint 2013 Management Shell. (Yes, I tried running it as administrator as well.) I get the following error:

`New-SPConfigurationDatabase : DOMAIN\USERNAME At line:1 char: 1
+ New-SPConfigurationDatabase
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo     : InvalidData: <Microsoft.Share...urationDatabase: SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase> [New-SPConfigurationDatabase], Win32EXception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase`

I've checked the Database Server, it uses Windows Authentication for the SQL Server, and uses the same user account I'm providing to SharePoint Configuration Wizard.

Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you provided the username in format `Domain\UserName`?

Comment: @AmalHashim Yes, I have.

Comment: Checked this http://nakedalm.com/issue-sharepoint-2013-the-username-is-invalid-the-account-must-be-a-valid-domain-account/ ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I get the error I posted as part of my question when I try running that command from the shell.

Comment: try with a different account.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE tried that as well. Created a new windows account on the Database Server, and tried using it on SharePoint Configuration Wizard, but still got the same error.

Comment: The account needs to be an Active Directory user account. Are you creating local Windows accounts, which will not work?

Comment: @TrevorSeward Yes, both the accounts I've been trying to use are local Windows accounts. SQL Server box is actually not on the domain, does it have to be?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 requires Active Directory. Technically you can use SQL accounts for that connectivity, but I wouldn't recommend it.